# The problem of not detecting the overlap status of the cards

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, backend, z-index

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
  <title>Game Cards App</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
  

  
<style>


#main-content {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
  animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}



.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5)); 
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

 
  
}
.card__back span {
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: white; 
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.tm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 

}

.tm-letter {
 
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    left: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Merkezden düzgün bir şekilde ayarlamak için */
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
   
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8); 
    
    
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
  
}


body.hoverEffect {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
    0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  /* Altın sarısı glow */
    0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, /* Mavi glow */
    0 0 150px 30px #000033; /* Koyu mavi shadow */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  /* Slightly transparent black to make the ambilight effect visible behind the card */
    color:#FFD700;   /* Altın sarısı text */
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #FFD700; /* Altın sarısı border */
}

#gameCardLink span {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

#gameCardLink span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.79em; 
  vertical-align: super; 
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
 }



.loader {

  border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
  border-radius: 80%;
  width: 12vw; 
  height: 12vw;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 44%; 
  top: 46%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); 
  }

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}




</style>
   
</head>





<body>

<div id="loading-animation">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-content">

  <div class="tm-container">
    <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
    <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
  </div>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
</audio>



<main>
   <div id="gameCardLink">
      <span>G</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>m</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span> </span> 
      <span> </span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>s</span>
      <span>®</span> 
   </div>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>


<ul>
  <li class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
      <iframe class="frame" 
      width="225"
      height="340"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
        <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
         <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
         <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
        <p class="card__num">2</p>
      </div>
      
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>771 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
        <p class="card__num">3</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
        <p class="card__num">4</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
        <p class="card__num">5</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
        <p class="card__num">6</p>
         </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>


<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();
  
</script>



<script>
<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
    const currentCard = $(this); 

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
        currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

     
        currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
            $(this).requestFullscreen();
        });

    }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
 
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

    $(this).find('.card__front').show();
    $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
    var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
    if (src) {
        $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
    }
});

</script>


<script>
var cardFlags = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");
  
  $(".card__front").click(function() {
    console.log('Kart önüne tıklandı', event.target);
    flipSound.currentTime = 0;
    flipSound.play();
    console.log('dönüş sesi çalındı', event.target);
  });

  
  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();
    console.log(cardId);
   
    
   
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

  
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
       
        console.log("is card flag true or false", cardId);

        if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
          startAnimation(div); 
          console.log("started");
          cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
          card.addClass("flipped");
        }
        
        // Adding canvas to back-side 
        var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
        if (div && canvas) {
          div.appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
      } else {
       
        console.log("stopped");
        card.removeClass("flipped");
        
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); 
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

</script>


<script>
    // Body's hoover effect
    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
    });

    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
    });
</script>


<script>

// Portal effect
var p5Instance;
function startAnimation(div) {
    // adding canvas to back-side 
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
    if (div && canvas) {
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    }

    const sketch = (p) => {

        const createParticleSystem = (location) => {
            const origin = location.copy();
            const particles = [];
            const addParticle = velocity => {
                const rand = p.random(0, 1);
                if (rand <= .3) {
                    particles.push(createSparkParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                } else {
                    particles.push(createParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                }
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                particles.forEach(particle => {
                    particle.applyForce(force);
                });
            };
            const run = () => {
                particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
                    particle.move();
                    particle.draw();

                    if (particle.isDead()) {
                        particles.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                origin,
                addParticle,
                run,
                applyForce
            };
        };

        const createSparkParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const particle = createParticle(locationP, velocity);
            let fade = 255;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB);
                p.stroke(16, 62, 100, fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4));
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(particle.location, arrow);
                p.line(particle.location.x, particle.location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                particle.applyForce(p.createVector(p.random(-.2, .2), p.random(-0.1, -0.4)));
                particle.velocity.add(particle.acc);
                particle.location.add(particle.velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4)));
                particle.acc.mult(0);
                fade -= 5;
            };
            return {
                ...particle,
                draw,
                move
            }
        }

        const createParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const location = locationP.copy();
            let fade = 255;
            const fadeMinus = p.randomGaussian(15, 2);
            let ligther = 100;
            let situate = 62;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB)
                p.stroke(16, p.constrain(situate, 62, 92), p.constrain(ligther, 60, 100), fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().mult(2);
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(location, arrow);
                p.line(location.x, location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                velocity.add(acc);
                location.add(velocity.copy().div(p.map(velocity.mag(), 18, 0, 5, 1)));
                acc.mult(0);
                fade -= fadeMinus;
                ligther -= 8;
                situate += 8;
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                acc.add(force);
            };
            const isDead = () => {
                if (fade < 0 || location.x < 0 || location.x > p.width || location.y > p.height) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move,
                applyForce,
                isDead,
                velocity,
                location,
                acc
            };
        };

        const createMover = () => {
            const location = p.createVector(p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            const velocity = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const mass = 10;
            let angle = 0;
            let angleVelocity = 0;
            let angleAcc = 0;
            let len = 100;
            const particleSystems = [
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location)
            ];
            const getGotoVector = angle => {
                const radius = p.map(angleVelocity, 0, 0.3, 0, 80);
                const goToVector = p.createVector(
                    location.x + radius * p.cos(angle),
                    location.y + radius * p.sin(angle)
                );
                return goToVector;
            };
            const draw = () => {
                const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle);
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    particleSystem.run();
                });
            };
            const renderParticleSystem = () => {
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle - p.random(0, p.TWO_PI));
                    const prepencular = p.createVector(
                     (goToVector.y - location.y)*-1,
                    (goToVector.x - location.x)
                    );
                    prepencular.normalize();
                    prepencular.mult(angleVelocity * 70);
                    particleSystem.origin.set(goToVector);
                    particleSystem.addParticle(prepencular);
                    const gravity = p.createVector(0, 0.3);
                    particleSystem.applyForce(gravity);
                });
            };
            const move = () => {
              
                angleAcc = 0.005;
                angleVelocity = p.constrain(angleVelocity + angleAcc, 0, 0.32);
                angle += angleVelocity;
                angleAcc = 0;
                renderParticleSystem();
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move
            };
        };

        let mover;

        p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(230, 320);
            p.clear(); 
            mover = createMover();
        }

        p.draw = function() {
            p.clear();
            mover.move();
            mover.draw();
        }
    };

    p5Instance = new p5(sketch);
}

</script>


<script>
// hiding and showing loading animation
  function hideLoadingAnimation() {
  console.log("Yükleme animasyonu gizleniyor, ana içerik gösteriliyor");
  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
  mainContent.style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Sayfa tamamen yüklendi");
  hideLoadingAnimation();
};

</script>


</html>
```

Hello friends, In the picture on the issue, there is a purple card turned upside down in the middle. There are 2 cards above and below that overlap with this card. While the cards overlap each other front and back, how can I easily ensure that the bottom side of the cards, whose front side is half visible, does not play trailers with hover (**mouse events will not work in this case**)?  with css? I am trying to solve this problem with very simple approaches.

```
card-partially-visible {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Does something like this make sense? If so, how should you determine if it is partially visible?
Could there be a ready-made function that will detect it automatically?

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's one heck of a block of code. But no, you'll have to write something like that yourself, determining overlap of bounding boxes using some basic geomtric maths.

Comment: You may be able to check the z-index of the cards on hover using JS, then conditionally add css style to all other cards using a class or something. But I am not sure how you are making the forefront cards z-index, is it dynamic in some way or hard coded?

Comment: @dale landry, The card's class z index appears as auto

Comment: @murattaşçı Only the two overlapped cards should be stopped or stopping all of the remaining will fine? If the latter, we can do it with help of  z-index. If not, we need to track whether the cards are overlapping or not.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to ensure that the trailer does not start with a hoover on cards whose face is half visible when any two cards overlap each other face to face. I only run the Hoover feature on cards whose front side is fully visible. @Akshay

Comment: Interesting, perhaps tracking the position of the cards left/top, etc and seeing if they overlap, much like you would using collision detection. well the "top" card def has to have a higher z-index, in your example code you are hard coding this as `9999`. So if you check each cards left position in relation to the window or their parents div, then you could determine which ones are "colliding" using the z-index as the 'top' card. I assume these cards are videos that are auto playing is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right, the video plays automatically when you wait 5 seconds with the mouse on the front of the cards. @dale landry

Comment: PS... hoover  != hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the live version**- https://overlap-status.tiiny.site/

The way the your code works, I could find only one way to track the overlapping without making drastic changes to your code. Z-index isn't enough as it can identify only the active card and not the cards that are being overlapped. Your code uses `transform: translate3d()` to displace the cards, so I utilised it.

**The solution:** First, find the active card by `getElementsByClassName('active')`, then get the values inside the `style.transform` and extract the `translate3d()` coordinations from it using `slice` and `split`. Then destructure them for further use. This gives you values of `x` and `y` of `translate3d()`. Now use the value of 'y' to check if the card is overlapping with the other two cards and if yes, then remove the `hover` event from these two cards. If after another click, the active card isn't overlapping with the cards anymore, then add the hover event back to the cards. I have named your anonymous hover functions, so I could use them with `on()` and `off()` methods. Also, this can be fine-tuned further by manipulating the checking values against the `y`.

*Following code doesn't include the **'// Portal effect'** script code. I have removed it because of Stackoverflow's character limit.* **You need to add it back.**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
      <title>Game Cards App</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
      
    <style>
    .card-partially-visible {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    #main-content {
      display: none;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
      animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
      color: white;
      font-family: "Lato";
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      max-width: 800px;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .card {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
      height: 340px;
      margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
      perspective: 1000;
     
    }
    .card:first-child .card__front {
      background:#5271C2;
    }
    
    .card__front img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    
    
    .card:first-child .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
    }
    .card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
      background:#35a541;
    }
    .card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
    }
    .card:nth-child(3) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
      background: #bdb235;
    }
    .card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
    }
    .card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
      background: #db6623;
    }
    .card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
    }
    .card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
      background: #3e5eb3;
    }
    .card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
    }
    .card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
      background: #aa9e5c;
    }
    .card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
      text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
    }
    .card:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .card__flipper {
      cursor: pointer;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
      border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6); 
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5)); 
    }
    .card__front, .card__back {
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 340px;
    }
    .card__front {
      transform: rotateY(0);
      z-index: 2;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .card__back {
      transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    
     
      
    }
    .card__back span {
      font-weight: bold; /* Metni kalın yap */
      color: white; /* Beyaz renk */
      font-size: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .card__name {
      font-size: 32px;
      line-height: 0.9;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .card__name span {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .card__num {
      font-size: 100px;
      margin: 0 8px 0 0;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      .card__num {
        font-size: 70px;
      }
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      .card {
        width: 100%;
        height: 290px;
        margin-right: 0;
        float: none;
      }
      .card .card__front,
      .card .card__back {
        height: 290px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    }
    
    /* Demo */
    main {
      text-align: center;
    }
    main h1, main p {
      margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    }
    main h1 {
      margin-top: 12px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    
    .fa-github {
      color: white; 
      font-size: 50px;
      margin-top: 8px; 
    }
    
    .tm-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center; 
      
    }
    
    .tm-letter {
     
      display:inline-block;
      font-size:30px;
      margin: 0 5px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(0);
      animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes letter-animation {
      0%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
      10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(-10px);
      }
      20%, 80% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
      }
    }
    
    #m-letter {
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }
    
    a {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    a::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
        left: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        width: 50px;
        height: 45px;
       
        
        border-radius: 50%; /* Eğer bir daire şeklinde efekt isteniyorsa */
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8); 
        
        
        filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); /
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
      
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    a:hover::before {
        opacity: 1;
      
    }
    
    
    body.hoverEffect {
          background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
    }
    
    #gameCard { 
        width: 300px;
        height: 450px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        box-shadow: 
        0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  
        0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, 
        0 0 150px 30px #000033; 
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  
        color:#FFD700;   
        text-align: center;
        border: 3px solid #FFD700; 
    }
    
    #gameCardLink span {
      font-size: 18px;
      margin-right: 5px; 
      font-weight: bold; 
    }
    
    #gameCardLink span:last-child {
      font-size: 0.79em; 
      vertical-align: super; 
      opacity: 0.9;
      font-weight: bold; 
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    }
    
    
    #loading-animation {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image:url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover ;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      z-index: 9999;
     }
    
    
    
    .loader {
    
      border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
      border-radius: 80%;
      width: 12vw; 
      height: 12vw; 
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
      position: absolute; 
      left: 44%; 
      top: 46%; /
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); /* Yuvarlak halkanın tam ortasında olması için bu dönüşümü kullanın. */
      }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    
    
    
    
    </style>
       
    </head>
    
    
    
    
    
    <body>
    
    <div id="loading-animation">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="main-content">
    
      <div class="tm-container">
        <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
        <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
      </div>
    
    
    <audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
      <source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
    
    
    
    <main>
       <div id="gameCardLink">
          <span>G</span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span>m</span>
          <span>e</span>
          <span> </span> <!-- Boşluk eklemek için span ekledik -->
          <span> </span>
          <span>C</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>r</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>d</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>s</span>
          <span>®</span>
       </div>
      <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
    </main>
    
    
    <ul>
      <li id='spider' class="card" >
        <div class="card__flipper">
          <div class="card__front">
            <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
            <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
            <p class="card__num">1</p>
          </div>
      
          
          <iframe class="frame" 
          width="225"
          height="340"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
          title="YouTube video player"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
          allowfullscreen
          ></iframe>
    
          
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
            <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
            <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
             <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
     
     
      <li id='batman' class="card">
        <div class="card__flipper">
           <div class="card__front">
             <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
             <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
            <p class="card__num">2</p>
          </div>
          
            <iframe class="frame" 
            width="225"
            height="340"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
    
          
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
              <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>771 Mil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li id='guard' class="card">
        <div class="card__flipper">
           <div class="card__front">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
            <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
            <p class="card__num">3</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" 
            width="225"
            height="340"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
            
         
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
             <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
       
      
      <li id='shazam' class="card">
        <div class="card__flipper">
           <div class="card__front">
           <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
            <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
            <p class="card__num">4</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" 
            width="225"
            height="340"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
            
            
         
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
             <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    
      <li id='flash' class="card">
        <div class="card__flipper">
           <div class="card__front">
            <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
            <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
            <p class="card__num">5</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" 
            width="225"
            height="340"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
            
            
         
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
              <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
     
      <li id='strange' class="card">
        <div class="card__flipper">
           <div class="card__front">
            <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
            <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
            <p class="card__num">6</p>
             </div>
            <iframe class="frame" 
            width="225"
            height="340"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            allowfullscreen
            ></iframe>
            
          
          <div class="card__back">
            <svg height="180" width="180">
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
              <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
              <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
            <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    
    
    <script>
    var Flipper = (function() {
      var card = $('.card');
      var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
      var win = $(window);
      
      var flip = function() {
        var thisCard = $(this);
        var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
        var offset = thisCard.offset();
        var xc = win.width() / 2;
        var yc = win.height() / 2;
        var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
        var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;
    
        var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
        var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
    //     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
        if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
        
        if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
            
        thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
        
        thisFlipper.css({
          'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
          '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
          '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
        }).addClass('active');
        
        
        return false;
      };
      
      var unflip = function(e) {
        card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
        flipper.css({
          'transform': 'none',
          '-webkit-transform': 'none',
          '-ms-transform': 'none'
        }).removeClass('active');
      };
      
      var bindActions = function() {
        card.on('click', flip);
        win.on('click', unflip);
      }
      
      var init = function() {
        bindActions();
      };
      
      return {
        init: init
      };
      
    }());
    Flipper.init();
      
    </script>
    
    
    
    <script>
    <!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->
    
    var hoverTimeout;
    
    function onHover() {
        const currentCard = $(this); 
    
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
            currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
            var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
            currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);
    
         
            currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
                $(this).requestFullscreen();
            });
    
        }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
     
    }
    function onHoverTime() {
        clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds
    
        $(this).find('.card__front').show();
        $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
        var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
        if (src) {
            $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
        }
    };
    
    </script>
    
    
    <script>
    var cardFlags = {};
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");
      // Sesin yalnızca kartın ön yüzüne tıklandığında çalmasını sağlayın.
      $(".card__front").click(function() {
    
        flipSound.currentTime = 0;
        flipSound.play();
    
      });
    
      
      $(".card").click(function() {
        var card = $(this);
        var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();
    
        
        // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
        if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
          card.addClass('flipping');
    
          // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
          if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
           
    
    
            if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
              startAnimation(div); 
    
              cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
              card.addClass("flipped");
            }
            
            // Adding canvas to back-side 
            var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
            var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
            if (div && canvas) {
              div.appendChild(canvas);
              canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
            }
          } else {
           
    
            card.removeClass("flipped");
            
          }
    
          setTimeout(function() {
            card.removeClass('flipping');
          }, 1000); 
        }
      });
    
      // Prevent sound on back side click
      $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
    });
    
    </script>
    
    
    <script>
        // Body's hoover effect
        document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
        });
    
        document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
        });
    </script>
    
    <script>
        let ind = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
        ind.forEach(c=> c.addEventListener('click', ))
    
        </script>
    
    
    
    <script>
    // hiding and showing loading animation
      function hideLoadingAnimation() {
    
      var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
      var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
      loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
      mainContent.style.display = "block";
    }
    window.onload = function() {
    
      hideLoadingAnimation();
    };
    
    </script>
    <script>
        let xt, yt;
        document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            let cord = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[1].style.transform; 
            [cx,cy,...rest]= cord.slice(12).split('px, ');
            console.log(cx,cy)
        })
        </script>
    <script> $('.card').on( "mouseenter", onHover).on( "mouseleave", onHoverTime );
           </script>
    
    <script>
        $(document.body).on('click', function(){
            if ( $("#batman").off( "mouseenter", onHover)){
                $('#batman, #flash').hover(onHover, onHoverTime);
                console.log('yes');
                }            
        })
        </script>
        
    <script>
    $(".card").click(function(){
            let cord = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[1].style.transform; 
            [cx,cy,...rest]= cord.slice(12).split('px, ');
            console.log(cx,cy);
            if ((cy<=300)&&(cy>=100)||((cy>(-300))&&(cy<(-60)))){
     
               $("#batman").off( "mouseenter", onHover);
                $("#flash").off( "mouseenter", onHover);
                
                console.log('offed');
                let hoverTimeout;
            }
            else{
                console.log('on');
                $('#batman, #flash').hover(onHover, onHoverTime);
            }
            
        });
        </script>
        
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Akshay, is this update valid for all overlaps between 6 cards? Additionally, can you share the entire code as a drive link?

Comment: @murattaşçı Yes, It works for all cards. Check out the live site, if that's what you are looking for I will upload it somewhere and share the link.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted, perfect.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked. Here is full code. https://github.com/akshyapatil/overlap/blob/main/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you move the 3D transition from the `.card__flipper` to the `.card` itself, you can give any `.card.active` `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, which will cover the cards behind.

In the working example below, I've made the pseudo-elements translucent red (ie. `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)`) so you can see them, but normally you would simply make the pseudo-elements transparent: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.addClass('active');
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).css({
      'transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
    flipper.removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();


<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->

let hoverTimeout;

$('.card').hover(function() {
    const currentCard = $(this); // Store the current card element in a variable

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
        currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

        // Add fullscreen functionality
        currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
            $(this).requestFullscreen();
        });

    }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
 
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

    $(this).find('.card__front').show();
    $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
    var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
    if (src) {
        $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
    }
});


var cardFlags = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");
  // Sesin yalnızca kartın ön yüzüne tıklandığında çalmasını sağlayın.
  $(".card__front").click(function() {
    console.log('Kart önüne tıklandı', event.target);
    flipSound.currentTime = 0;
    flipSound.play();
    console.log('dönüş sesi çalındı', event.target);
  });

  
  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();
    console.log(cardId);
   
    
    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
       
        console.log("is card flag true or false", cardId);

        if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
          startAnimation(div); 
          console.log("started");
          cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
          card.addClass("flipped");
        }
        
        // Adding canvas to back-side 
        var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
        if (div && canvas) {
          div.appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
      } else {
       
        console.log("stopped");
        card.removeClass("flipped");
        
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); 
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});




    // Body's hoover effect
    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
    });

    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
    });

// Portal effect
var p5Instance;
function startAnimation(div) {
    // adding canvas to back-side 
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
    if (div && canvas) {
        div.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
    }

    const sketch = (p) => {

        const createParticleSystem = (location) => {
            const origin = location.copy();
            const particles = [];
            const addParticle = velocity => {
                const rand = p.random(0, 1);
                if (rand <= .3) {
                    particles.push(createSparkParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                } else {
                    particles.push(createParticle(origin, velocity.copy()));
                }
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                particles.forEach(particle => {
                    particle.applyForce(force);
                });
            };
            const run = () => {
                particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
                    particle.move();
                    particle.draw();

                    if (particle.isDead()) {
                        particles.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            };
            return {
                origin,
                addParticle,
                run,
                applyForce
            };
        };

        const createSparkParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const particle = createParticle(locationP, velocity);
            let fade = 255;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB);
                p.stroke(16, 62, 100, fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4));
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(particle.location, arrow);
                p.line(particle.location.x, particle.location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                particle.applyForce(p.createVector(p.random(-.2, .2), p.random(-0.1, -0.4)));
                particle.velocity.add(particle.acc);
                particle.location.add(particle.velocity.copy().normalize().mult(p.random(2, 4)));
                particle.acc.mult(0);
                fade -= 5;
            };
            return {
                ...particle,
                draw,
                move
            }
        }

        const createParticle = (locationP, velocity) => {
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const location = locationP.copy();
            let fade = 255;
            const fadeMinus = p.randomGaussian(15, 2);
            let ligther = 100;
            let situate = 62;
            const draw = () => {
                p.colorMode(p.HSB)
                p.stroke(16, p.constrain(situate, 62, 92), p.constrain(ligther, 60, 100), fade);
                const arrow = velocity.copy().mult(2);
                const direction = p5.Vector.add(location, arrow);
                p.line(location.x, location.y, direction.x, direction.y);
            };
            const move = () => {
                velocity.add(acc);
                location.add(velocity.copy().div(p.map(velocity.mag(), 18, 0, 5, 1)));
                acc.mult(0);
                fade -= fadeMinus;
                ligther -= 8;
                situate += 8;
            };
            const applyForce = force => {
                acc.add(force);
            };
            const isDead = () => {
                if (fade < 0 || location.x < 0 || location.x > p.width || location.y > p.height) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move,
                applyForce,
                isDead,
                velocity,
                location,
                acc
            };
        };

        const createMover = () => {
            const location = p.createVector(p.width / 2, p.height / 2);
            const velocity = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const acc = p.createVector(0, 0);
            const mass = 10;
            let angle = 0;
            let angleVelocity = 0;
            let angleAcc = 0;
            let len = 100;
            const particleSystems = [
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location),
                createParticleSystem(location)
            ];
            const getGotoVector = angle => {
                const radius = p.map(angleVelocity, 0, 0.3, 0, 80);
                const goToVector = p.createVector(
                    location.x + radius * p.cos(angle),
                    location.y + radius * p.sin(angle)
                );
                return goToVector;
            };
            const draw = () => {
                const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle);
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    particleSystem.run();
                });
            };
            const renderParticleSystem = () => {
                particleSystems.forEach(particleSystem => {
                    const goToVector = getGotoVector(angle - p.random(0, p.TWO_PI));
                    const prepencular = p.createVector(
                     (goToVector.y - location.y)*-1,
                    (goToVector.x - location.x)
                    );
                    prepencular.normalize();
                    prepencular.mult(angleVelocity * 70);
                    particleSystem.origin.set(goToVector);
                    particleSystem.addParticle(prepencular);
                    const gravity = p.createVector(0, 0.3);
                    particleSystem.applyForce(gravity);
                });
            };
            const move = () => {
              
                angleAcc = 0.005;
                angleVelocity = p.constrain(angleVelocity + angleAcc, 0, 0.32);
                angle += angleVelocity;
                angleAcc = 0;
                renderParticleSystem();
            };
            return {
                draw,
                move
            };
        };

        let mover;

        p.setup = function() {
            p.createCanvas(230, 320);
            p.clear(); 
            mover = createMover();
        }

        p.draw = function() {
            p.clear();
            mover.move();
            mover.draw();
        }
    };

    p5Instance = new p5(sketch);
}


// hiding and showing loading animation
  function hideLoadingAnimation() {
  console.log("Yükleme animasyonu gizleniyor, ana içerik gösteriliyor");
  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
  mainContent.style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Sayfa tamamen yüklendi");
  hideLoadingAnimation();
};
```

```css
.card.active::before,
.card.active::after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  z-index: 12;
  display: block;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card.active::before {
  margin-top: -260px;
}

#main-content {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
  animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5));
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

 
  
}
.card__back span {
  font-weight: bold; /* Metni kalın yap */
  color: white; /* Beyaz renk */
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px; 
}

.tm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  
}

.tm-letter {
 
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    left: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
   
    
    border-radius: 50%; /* Eğer bir daire şeklinde efekt isteniyorsa */
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8); 
    
    
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); /
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
  
}


body.hoverEffect {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
    0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  
    0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, 
    0 0 150px 30px #000033; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  
    color:#FFD700;   
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #FFD700; 
}

#gameCardLink span {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

#gameCardLink span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.79em; 
  vertical-align: super; 
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}


#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
 }



.loader {

  border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
  border-radius: 80%;
  width: 12vw; 
  height: 12vw; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 44%; 
  top: 46%; /
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); /* Yuvarlak halkanın tam ortasında olması için bu dönüşümü kullanın. */
  }

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 

<div id="loading-animation">
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
<div class="tm-container">
<div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
<div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
</div>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
<source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<main>
<div id="gameCardLink">
<span>G</span>
<span>a</span>
<span>m</span>
<span>e</span>
<span> </span> <!-- Boşluk eklemek için span ekledik -->
<span> </span>
<span>C</span>
<span> </span>
<span>a</span>
<span> </span>
<span>r</span>
<span> </span>
<span>d</span>
<span> </span>
<span>s</span>
<span>®</span>
</div>
<p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>


<ul>
<li class="card" >
<div class="card__flipper">
<div class="card__front">
<img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
<p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
<p class="card__num">1</p>
</div>
  
      
<iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 
<div class="card__back">
<svg height="180" width="180">
<circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
<!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
<circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
<span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
</div>
</div>
</li>
 
 
<li class="card">
<div class="card__flipper">
<div class="card__front">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
<p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
<p class="card__num">2</p>
</div>
      
<iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>771 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
        <p class="card__num">3</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
        <p class="card__num">4</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
        <p class="card__num">5</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
        <p class="card__num">6</p>
         </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Makes no sense, with the above example the UI seems quite oddly broken, if you tap the read areas the card goes back as active. That behavior is not consistent for when you tap the cards on the left/right... not sure if that's desired - expected.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, the solution idea seemed creative, if you are wondering about the answer given, but yes it breaks the UI. The appearance and original movement of the cards are distorted